# Import a table so field is all lowercase

Tags: mysql

Not sure it is possible, but I am trying to import a large set of data and I want to make the cases for certain fields to be imported as all lowercase. I know how to do it once the data is loaded but it takes forever so was looking to do it as I imported it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a database  trigger which will ensure that all characters are coverted to lowercase before storing in a particular filed

CREATE TRIGGER lc_ins BEFORE INSERT ON tablename FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.fieldname = LOWER(NEW.fieldname);

CREATE TRIGGER lc_upd BEFORE UPDATE ON tablename FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.fieldname = LOWER(NEW.fieldname);

Comment: Sorry I am new at sql - how would I incorporate this into my load data  local infile statement?

Comment: The above triggers should be created before your data load using your 'LOAD DATA INFILE 'filename' statement. Just type them in the sql box . Then after creation of the triggers load your data. You cannot create triggers from within your LOAD DATA statement.

Comment: Bobby this is awesome - had no idea about triggers before and just spent some time learning about them this helps a ton.